# Avoid the height change of a container + how to position a list item at end

Tags: css

In the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/6aPyv/1/) I am making a vertical menu. When someone hovers on the icon, I want the description of that menu to become visible (with fade effects).

Q1:  However during the transition time of the fade, the text of the description causes the text to wrap into a newline thus making the transition jerky. Any solutions how to solve this problem?

Q2: I would want the "Extend All" to be positioned at the bottom. However in HTML i need it to be at the start since I am using ~ in CSS. Can I rearrange that using CSS/CSS3?

Thanks

CODE:

```
#nav {
    margin: 50px;
    width: 50px;

}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;

}

#nav ul li{
  width:55px;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans";
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;

    background: #67BCDB;    
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;    


    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;   
}

#nav ul li a{
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   display:none;
   /* overflow-y: scroll;*/
    overflow:auto;
}
#nav:hover {
  width:30px;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
  width:300px;
}

#nav ul li:hover a{
  display:inline;
}
#extendList {
  vertical-align: bottom;
} 
#extendList:hover ~ .oList{
  width:300px;
}

#extendList:hover ~ .oList a{
  display:inline;
}

span {
 margin:0 20px;   
}
```

Comment: you can give height to LI and make it overflow hidden. here is my solution http://jsfiddle.net/6aPyv/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To avoid text to wrap , you may use : `white-space` with `nowrap` as
   value;
2. to fade with `transition` or `animation` , you need a rule that has numbers value, you
   may use `opacity`, **not** `display` **nor** `visibility`.
3. to change order you may use `display:flex` and `order` on childs. **[demo pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xutlC)** /**[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aPyv/6/)**

Comment: Tx for the first answer - its working. However my second question is how to position the "Expand All" as the last item of the list (instead of first element). Tks